# Is there a character limit for REST Here Maps routing api request?

Tags: here-maps-rest, heremaps

**This API works fine if I am passing around 50 or 60 waypoints.** 
I am currently getting Empty reply from server

```
"curl 'https://route.api.here.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?jsoncallback=jQuery321030886563148208523_1588226597554&app_id=APP_ID&app_code=APP_CODE&mode=fastest%3Bcar%3B&waypoint0=13.055972866472336%2C%2078.01994197494206&waypoint1=13.056257412712744%2C78.02011212845024&waypoint2=13.056457444761685%2C78.02023351562264&waypoint3=13.056673405208578%2C78.02036456876203&waypoint4=13.056868110695888%2C78.02048270225077&waypoint5=13.057062549177289%2C78.02059859841785&waypoint6=13.057252151214083%2C78.0207095646235&waypoint7=13.057455761941554%2C78.0207915020337&waypoint8=13.057740204892355%2C78.02088635675757&waypoint9=13.058791164408287%2C78.02123470989947&waypoint10=13.059005907970324%2C78.02130568734867&waypoint11=13.059184445940936%2C78.02136469805717&waypoint12=13.059350674211414%2C78.02141960464354&waypoint13=13.059541107601396%2C78.0214825058419&waypoint14=13.059726559671525%2C78.02154376168286&waypoint15=13.060361195229719%2C78.02146559116646&waypoint16=13.060788240589602%2C78.019945082155&waypoint17=13.060865814169642%2C78.01969318808878&waypoint18=13.060958628882682%2C78.01942137351186&waypoint19=13.061059695388815%2C78.01914290214192&waypoint20=13.061165855105576%2C78.01885652857142&waypoint21=13.061271853921898%2C78.01856560679353&waypoint22=13.061377477100315%2C78.01827189159592&waypoint23=13.061490927804467%2C78.01798181184891&waypoint24=13.061603077079283%2C78.01771348277819&waypoint25=13.061713958757585%2C78.01748487382635&waypoint26=13.061761119751093%2C78.0173937423634&waypoint27=13.061764417413794%2C78.01738737013066&waypoint28=13.061763060648929%2C78.01738999187288&waypoint29=13.061763904121634%2C78.01738836198987&waypoint30=13.061770309413504%2C78.01737636193968&waypoint31=13.061788887350271%2C78.01734166838297&waypoint32=13.06271987921685%2C78.015601701824&waypoint33=13.062811301109639%2C78.01542277811033&waypoint34=13.062911739641459%2C78.01522620774233&waypoint35=13.063016699830074%2C78.0150205318817&waypoint36=13.06312453607604%2C78.01480868262749&waypoint37=13.06324032086656%2C78.01458078677975&waypoint38=13.063291938797324%2C78.01432378105397&waypoint39=13.063290958104332%2C78.01404624210745&waypoint40=13.063247505644636%2C78.01378723676622&waypoint41=13.063224431654243%2C78.01351650548693&waypoint42=13.0632314209409%2C78.0132458814278&waypoint43=13.063248747640435%2C78.01299459615882&waypoint44=13.063282739948368%2C78.01274138914167&waypoint45=13.06332379072634%2C78.01249627445624&waypoint46=13.063354485566494%2C78.01231536091063&waypoint47=13.063522707883003%2C78.01114308321519&waypoint48=13.063539265519093%2C78.01077608445995&waypoint49=13.06354830329796%2C78.01059931724072&waypoint50=13.063558779113528%2C78.01039979787036&waypoint51=13.063570513517206%2C78.01019689499198&waypoint52=13.063585757429564%2C78.00997676867613&waypoint53=13.063605629122156%2C78.00973312829262&waypoint54=13.063628478816375%2C78.0094919964221&waypoint55=13.063654228800601%2C78.00924381901922&waypoint56=13.063678988657387%2C78.00900985275085&waypoint57=13.063694494771383%2C78.00886332897811&waypoint58=13.06370299240077%2C78.00878303131505&waypoint59=13.063716484723836%2C78.00865553669719&waypoint60=13.063732081279467%2C78.00850815830351&waypoint61=13.063751001388036%2C78.00832147406369&waypoint62=13.06376634705606%2C78.00814285294018&waypoint63=13.063690629701984%2C78.00532314711427&waypoint64=13.063694121351578%2C78.0050738229828&waypoint65=13.0637123884021%2C78.00481625358222&waypoint66=13.063731164665892%2C78.00455150416342&waypoint67=13.063749539088677%2C78.00429242079052&waypoint68=13.063768171436823%2C78.00402970061371&waypoint69=13.063789398890064%2C78.00377847967032&waypoint70=13.06379338727618%2C78.00363041467779&waypoint71=13.063809396711237%2C78.00354634418898&waypoint72=13.063788148586697%2C78.00344416878931&waypoint73=13.06371447165782%2C78.00337359316461&waypoint74=13.063630359259493%2C78.00331190235727&waypoint75=13.063569506642468%2C78.00319899812155&waypoint76=13.064167681162305%2C78.00155991695635&waypoint77=13.064198358927912%2C78.00145296387188&waypoint78=13.064237502415724%2C78.00128733746521&waypoint79=13.06426960510487%2C78.00113017678075&waypoint80=13.064282471326239%2C78.00095608465188&waypoint81=13.064297097747273%2C78.00080982044153&waypoint82=13.064324841846771%2C78.00065886236541&waypoint83=13.064350406651444%2C78.00050480298512&waypoint84=13.064370607038088%2C78.00033599145524&waypoint85=13.064389131044097%2C78.00018779940717&waypoint86=13.06439780631388%2C78.0000808463227&waypoint87=13.06441226509685%2C77.99995302229934&waypoint88=13.064440009196348%2C77.99977708615177&waypoint89=13.064477099117882%2C77.99957407645695&waypoint90=13.064516494062788%2C77.99933460548334&waypoint91=13.06457353291387%2C77.99644687220267&waypoint92=13.064405224298186%2C77.99629088498465&waypoint93=13.064243746933586%2C77.99614747062138&waypoint94=13.064068104152627%2C77.99598989084176&waypoint95=13.063921253209061%2C77.99583055086246&waypoint96=13.06379489601875%2C77.99568277790955&waypoint97=13.06371061598236%2C77.9955182411503&waypoint98=13.063663425867505%2C77.99535563222877&waypoint99=13.063635388401396%2C77.99519436441174&waypoint100=13.063589371752984%2C77.99505664974264&waypoint101=13.063536481943972%2C77.99493402249924&waypoint102=13.063488369819767%2C77.99481282017938&waypoint103=13.063469803904242%2C77.99469379715434&waypoint104=13.06344059297169%2C77.99457804307154&waypoint105=13.063363311824448%2C77.99394872978142&waypoint106=13.0636705504852%2C77.99282689586094&waypoint107=13.06369888131792%2C77.99271726056746&waypoint108=13.063729014259822%2C77.99260259613207&waypoint109=13.063762960967667%2C77.99247971743158&waypoint110=13.063795273204393%2C77.99231333665362&waypoint111=13.063836051163323%2C77.99211510464362&waypoint112=13.063818616804726%2C77.99195744104496&waypoint113=13.063796656218416%2C77.99185518182627&waypoint114=13.063804367569334%2C77.99170841470173&waypoint115=13.063833913778014%2C77.99153088599256&waypoint116=13.063834332873173%2C77.99132100313714&waypoint117=13.06381492876733%2C77.99110315747372&waypoint118=13.06378144306416%2C77.99097206450811&waypoint119=13.064062446367986%2C77.9889589828234&waypoint120=13.06409559679503%2C77.98883333809486&waypoint121=13.064117557381339%2C77.98870660371891&waypoint122=13.0641644960391%2C77.98858489848486&waypoint123=13.06422388182307%2C77.98846411526016&waypoint124=13.064275220979995%2C77.98832598149589&waypoint125=13.064288673934586%2C77.98824358738771&waypoint126=13.06434407831455%2C77.98814107671193&waypoint127=13.064394537371642%2C77.98800998374632&waypoint128=13.064439296734578%2C77.98791174784115&waypoint129=13.064489504334576%2C77.98779339536837&waypoint130=13.064535311435408%2C77.98766867264918&waypoint131=13.064573993918545%2C77.98752249225787&waypoint132=13.064590045263119%2C77.9874015413951&waypoint133=13.065199451533207%2C77.98671430915407&waypoint134=13.065400910575935%2C77.98673283316008&waypoint135=13.065602579166242%2C77.98674582510999&waypoint136=13.065822939400622%2C77.98673945486358&waypoint137=13.066040114511797%2C77.98673165969363&waypoint138=13.066265378159532%2C77.98674155033937&waypoint139=13.066488755879053%2C77.98674473546258&waypoint140=13.06670924184198%2C77.98676443293503&waypoint141=13.066926333134125%2C77.98675873324088&waypoint142=13.067162744713078%2C77.98676158308795&waypoint143=13.06742304471607%2C77.98678035855106&waypoint144=13.067674250354122%2C77.98681564636341&waypoint145=13.067931993876647%2C77.98680617481283&waypoint146=13.06909649168427%2C77.9868124612402&waypoint147=13.072085520264759%2C77.98679100356809&waypoint148=13.072404367861404%2C77.98679930165223&waypoint149=13.072731178266064%2C77.98680366024188&waypoint150=13.073065616202609%2C77.98681681982985&waypoint151=13.073402694438652%2C77.98683400273136&waypoint152=13.073726152082042%2C77.98684825196675&waypoint153=13.074052124296383%2C77.98685772351733&waypoint154=13.074384843942777%2C77.98686141155473&waypoint155=13.074707798671978%2C77.98686593778244&waypoint156=13.075029160839575%2C77.9868608248215&waypoint157=13.075338285428542%2C77.98685194000414&waypoint158=13.075679931801814%2C77.98686183064989&waypoint159=13.077212227520604%2C77.98687943264655&waypoint160=13.080226317991578%2C77.98688764691165&waypoint161=13.080551829201244%2C77.98688999384454&waypoint162=13.080865899113082%2C77.98688915565423&waypoint163=13.081159978185855%2C77.98686845235339&waypoint164=13.081471491617226%2C77.98686258502117&waypoint165=13.081776131887995%2C77.9868613277357&waypoint166=13.08209854179349%2C77.98686241738311&waypoint167=13.082431261439885%2C77.98686157919279&waypoint168=13.082757610839868%2C77.98685881316474&waypoint169=13.083084421244527%2C77.98686258502117&waypoint170=13.083413997677232%2C77.986878007723&waypoint171=13.08376226575401%2C77.98685705296508&waypoint172=13.084097122785714%2C77.98685755587927&waypoint173=13.085383577284482%2C77.98682067550531&waypoint174=13.087544306193559%2C77.98687733717075&waypoint175=13.087794631731777%2C77.98690591946057&waypoint176=13.088064780470997%2C77.98696987338177&waypoint177=13.08833660559085%2C77.98711077317408&waypoint178=13.088614549500019%2C77.98727765686623&waypoint179=13.08890196495977%2C77.98745635904184&waypoint180=13.089187410672277%2C77.98764126382581&waypoint181=13.089479645726353%2C77.98784611753932&waypoint182=13.089799080056222%2C77.98802909448555&waypoint183=13.090148186323317%2C77.98815624795667&waypoint184=13.090476547380062%2C77.98826898455432&waypoint185=13.090799585928293%2C77.98838214024714&waypoint186=13.091111308907243%2C77.98846486963144&waypoint187=13.092410545808349%2C77.98881238333693&waypoint188=13.095299117279326%2C77.9881769512575&waypoint189=13.095620353718378%2C77.98808634288422&waypoint190=13.095949636784471%2C77.98799020245484&waypoint191=13.096291199338712%2C77.98789976171962&waypoint192=13.096643365000464%2C77.98781611032597&waypoint193=13.096989453782417%2C77.98770345754734&waypoint194=13.097327915032484%2C77.987596839739&waypoint195=13.097598147590736%2C77.98752467155269&waypoint196=13.097717044887224%2C77.98748737208358&waypoint197=13.097835145902911%2C77.9874480609577&waypoint198=13.09801342898337%2C77.98741134822181&waypoint199=13.09818056413261%2C77.98735267489961&waypoint200=13.099056850199679%2C77.98711437739244&waypoint201=13.101534373139126%2C77.98639873049966&waypoint202=13.101731180225594%2C77.98634667888096&waypoint203=13.101955647592527%2C77.98630837358347&waypoint204=13.10220329092173%2C77.98629730947128&waypoint205=13.102461118263287%2C77.98629236414841&waypoint206=13.102724310022873%2C77.98629881821385&waypoint207=13.103008456540389%2C77.98630284152738&waypoint208=13.10329084285824%2C77.98631792895308&waypoint209=13.103572055709645%2C77.9863237962853&waypoint210=13.103757505317315%2C77.98633879989198&waypoint211=13.103830134508296%2C77.98632756814173&waypoint212=13.103922419262215%2C77.9863237962853&waypoint213=13.10406461824952%2C77.98628641299716&waypoint214=13.104235441436156%2C77.98627266667596&waypoint215=13.105128323671506%2C77.98636788509599&waypoint216=13.109599272732725%2C77.9868801031988&waypoint217=13.110013296839883%2C77.98694824807158&waypoint218=13.110417849396457%2C77.98702117062918&waypoint219=13.110817163263551%2C77.98709325499645&waypoint220=13.11118211132764%2C77.98714865937642&waypoint221=13.111510765750996%2C77.98721043400279&waypoint222=13.11181586702644%2C77.98726659275404&waypoint223=13.112140623864821%2C77.98732694245687&waypoint224=13.112495304097525%2C77.9873930756729&waypoint225=13.112862682913535%2C77.98748175620845&waypoint226=13.113233288762265%2C77.98756817363015&waypoint227=13.113610264857405%2C77.9876642302405&waypoint228=13.113996712503129%2C77.98774084083549&waypoint229=13.114385590900772%2C77.98783027574233&waypoint230=13.114757370215948%2C77.9879229795914&waypoint231=13.116093026486332%2C77.98831349246016&waypoint232=13.115928196360464%2C77.98827677972427&waypoint233=13.115730509174163%2C77.98823453493229&waypoint234=13.11551777647167%2C77.9881854169797&waypoint235=13.115280359064336%2C77.98813537701777&waypoint236=13.11500958168238%2C77.98807427294365&waypoint237=13.114717556175883%2C77.98800579279474&waypoint238=13.11439552345603%2C77.98793236732295&waypoint239=13.114078897063726%2C77.98785919330827&waypoint240=13.113762941223674%2C77.98779364682547&waypoint241=13.113460522157245%2C77.98772089190594&waypoint242=13.11315412168681%2C77.98766464933566&waypoint243=13.112862179999345%2C77.98759440898708&waypoint244=13.112567975198022%2C77.98753380782715&waypoint245=13.112524137844435%2C77.98753481365553&waypoint246=13.112510140066139%2C77.9875400104355&waypoint247=13.112042555597714%2C77.98746163964084&waypoint248=13.111893399630777%2C77.98741461716405&waypoint249=13.11173087452828%2C77.98737639568559&waypoint250=13.11155129225283%2C77.98734387390128&waypoint251=13.111373051081888%2C77.98729542650095&waypoint252=13.111216477130643%2C77.98726801767758&waypoint253=13.111184416351012%2C77.98726608983985&waypoint254=13.111180309218458%2C77.98726282089761&waypoint255=13.111173897062532%2C77.98727874651364&waypoint256=13.111173897062532%2C77.98727874651364&waypoint257=13.111173897062532%2C77.98727874651364&waypoint258=13.111173897062532%2C77.98727874651364&waypoint259=13.111173897062532%2C77.98727874651364&waypoint260=13.111182865698925%2C77.98727028079144&waypoint261=13.11114133336871%2C77.9872530140709&waypoint262=13.109233360749771%2C77.98768920831195&waypoint263=13.109377403755774%2C77.98777805648557&waypoint264=13.109578611341407%2C77.98779892742446&waypoint265=13.109800815594484%2C77.98785567290894&waypoint266=13.110049171385457%2C77.98789875589124&waypoint267=13.11031240505456%2C77.98794435344449&waypoint268=13.110585529369404%2C77.98799338757804&waypoint269=13.110847296205453%2C77.98803890131227&waypoint270=13.111015604821137%2C77.98809464096836&waypoint271=13.11106971000611%2C77.9882393126171&waypoint272=13.111062669207445%2C77.98834500841609&waypoint273=13.111062669207445%2C77.98834500841609&waypoint274=13.111062669207445%2C77.98834500841609&waypoint275=13.111062669207445%2C77.98834500841609&waypoint276=13.111059316446177%2C77.98833503395132&waypoint277=13.111059316446177%2C77.98833503395132&waypoint278=13.111059316446177%2C77.98833503395132&waypoint279=13.111059316446177%2C77.98833503395132&waypoint280=13.111059316446177%2C77.98833503395132&waypoint281=13.111059316446177%2C77.98833503395132&waypoint282=13.111059316446177%2C77.98833503395132&waypoint283=13.111059316446177%2C77.98833503395132&waypoint284=13.111059316446177%2C77.98833503395132&waypoint285=13.111059316446177%2C77.98833503395132&waypoint286=13.111059316446177%2C77.98833503395132&waypoint287=13.111059316446177%2C77.98833503395132&waypoint288=13.111059316446177%2C77.98833503395132&waypoint289=13.111059316446177%2C77.98833503395132&waypoint290=13.111059316446177%2C77.98833503395132&waypoint291=13.111059316446177%2C77.98833503395132&waypoint292=13.111059316446177%2C77.98833503395132&waypoint293=13.111059316446177%2C77.98833503395132&waypoint294=13.111059316446177%2C77.98833503395132&waypoint295=13.111059316446177%2C77.98833503395132&waypoint296=13.111059316446177%2C77.98833503395132&waypoint297=13.111059316446177%2C77.98833503395132&waypoint298=13.11105139554768%2C77.98834031455031&waypoint299=13.11105139554768%2C77.98834031455031&waypoint300=13.11105139554768%2C77.98834031455031&waypoint301=13.11105139554768%2C77.98834031455031&waypoint302=13.11105139554768%2C77.98834031455031&waypoint303=13.11105139554768%2C77.98834031455031&waypoint304=13.11105139554768%2C77.98834031455031&waypoint305=13.11105139554768%2C77.98834031455031&waypoint306=13.11105139554768%2C77.98834031455031&waypoint307=13.11105139554768%2C77.98834031455031&waypoint308=13.11105139554768%2C77.98834031455031&waypoint309=13.11105139554768%2C77.98834031455031&waypoint310=13.11105139554768%2C77.98834031455031&waypoint311=13.11105139554768%2C77.98834031455031&waypoint312=13.11105139554768%2C77.98834031455031&waypoint313=13.11105139554768%2C77.98834031455031&waypoint314=13.11105139554768%2C77.98834031455031&waypoint315=13.11105139554768%2C77.98834031455031&waypoint316=13.11105139554768%2C77.98834031455031&waypoint317=13.11105139554768%2C77.98834031455031&waypoint318=13.11105139554768%2C77.98834031455031&waypoint319=13.11105139554768%2C77.98834031455031&waypoint320=13.11105139554768%2C77.98834031455031&waypoint321=13.11105139554768%2C77.98834031455031&waypoint322=13.11105139554768%2C77.98834031455031&waypoint323=13.11105139554768%2C77.98834031455031&waypoint324=13.11105139554768%2C77.98834031455031&waypoint325=13.11105139554768%2C77.98834031455031&waypoint326=13.11105139554768%2C77.98834031455031&waypoint327=13.11105139554768%2C77.98834031455031&waypoint328=13.11105139554768%2C77.98834031455031&waypoint329=13.11105139554768%2C77.98834031455031&waypoint330=13.11105139554768%2C77.98834031455031&waypoint331=13.11105139554768%2C77.98834031455031&waypoint332=13.11105139554768%2C77.98834031455031&waypoint333=13.11105139554768%2C77.98834031455031&waypoint334=13.11105139554768%2C77.98834031455031&waypoint335=13.11105139554768%2C77.98834031455031&waypoint336=13.11105139554768%2C77.98834031455031&waypoint337=13.11105139554768%2C77.98834031455031&waypoint338=13.11105139554768%2C77.98834031455031&waypoint339=13.11105139554768%2C77.98834031455031&waypoint340=13.11105139554768%2C77.98834031455031&waypoint341=13.11105139554768%2C77.98834031455031&waypoint342=13.111054454942337%2C77.98833981163612&waypoint343=13.111054454942337%2C77.98833981163612&waypoint344=13.111054454942337%2C77.98833981163612&waypoint345=13.111054454942337%2C77.98833981163612&waypoint346=13.111054454942337%2C77.98833981163612&waypoint347=13.111054454942337%2C77.98833981163612&waypoint348=13.111054454942337%2C77.98833981163612&waypoint349=13.111054454942337%2C77.98833981163612&waypoint350=13.111054454942337%2C77.98833981163612&waypoint351=13.111054454942337%2C77.98833981163612&waypoint352=13.111054454942337%2C77.98833981163612&waypoint353=13.111054454942337%2C77.98833981163612&waypoint354=13.111054454942337%2C77.98833981163612&waypoint355=13.111054454942337%2C77.98833981163612&waypoint356=13.111054454942337%2C77.98833981163612&waypoint357=13.111054454942337%2C77.98833981163612&waypoint358=13.111054454942337%2C77.98833981163612&waypoint359=13.111054454942337%2C77.98833981163612&waypoint360=13.111054454942337%2C77.98833981163612&waypoint361=13.111071637843839%2C%2077.98834752298704&_=1588226597556' \
  -H 'authority: route.api.here.com' \
  -H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.122 Mobile Safari/537.36' \
  -H 'accept: */*' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-site: cross-site' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-mode: no-cors' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-dest: script' \
  -H 'referer: http://localhost:4200/trips/887_1585385671783' \
  -H 'accept-language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8' \
  -H 'cookie: CONSENTMGR=ts:1581564470018%7Cconsent:true; _fltpm=true; s_fid=05454FE372A3D148-11F9D40EA74745B3; _mkto_trk=id:142-UEL-347&token:_mch-here.com-1581564470096-99796; _gcl_au=1.1.1412298891.1581564470; _biz_uid=ba693477264c4199acb60ece8447f9c7; locale=en-GB; s_prop56=16; AMCV_E16CD4415481B5550A4C98A2%40AdobeOrg=432708069%7CMCMID%7C24083277236489400023934932908985334942%7CMCAAMLH-1587982682%7C12%7CMCAAMB-1587982682%7Cj8Odv6LonN4r3an7LhD3WZrU1bUpAkFkkiY1ncBR96t2PTI%7CMCAID%7C2F22611B0515B580-600001608027327E; _biz_flagsA=%7B%22Version%22%3A1%2C%22Mkto%22%3A%221%22%2C%22XDomain%22%3A%221%22%2C%22Ecid%22%3A%221848617127%22%7D; s_nr=1587378302681-New; here_ca_access=true; here_access=h1.MzBBUHtVknhNkwaM0rzrxg.rtwqWTFI4P_F0YrBULGrDcLVPAirKmXNySGYWYvA7blxcoQ7aFaDjUmo1najNWTqbCj18OxQo5iGReqyd2Sj6cp_q750M97-Y65s2ojzK3CQwYo7Lj9U5hpGFwz6SJqk6oUVKTlY34gmYkkUoreuOEWpeTnJeY-yexGvRCLtljr1wBUjU2USN4bMV1ICVatK3spwiosVYyuUeZV1ZwDGCkXAwIEK9jec4oJ0RqjVH8BgeSAPg8Sw7CYU5OUNkYHWQVDqXTvS6vJAJivnGyrQaBm0OknmeXqDqmDxQqJDEGIO7dxZx_y39MgeWW0y2OT7QL5OuAWv97nnV6M49vL02sS1A3ExdBag0FAJ2jmH9JnKCiigg8PP7J7BkVTkkIksBlgBGP-ZPIqEH_bStIMmBcp8f7OneGK-xGNU2s3Mg-z7pj7kwkqeMVhk744_7ySYmiK8_Ayy-3DfbtBD7PsLyw.USo_8r7LQMpjI4x3SPekANBSyiq8zqm2ymqjC1Df_YjyJj8s8mgHPt26MraCLqRToGkCpwi8uVFz0VK4mcVvHySUpo2Piuv4zOLOcTjyvsiI0E2qbScFkAcqGvWdniFZ0fU8Y7qbVkOrp9A2JW7NDPrmhR5LZGuyKt0UQO-8BW13oD5qS6Ntcd61AtkNwuzT0ClD6GTehOCnnf6Rw7ea2RGoVNTc0vGzE8X39a3OF4cRx1mB6oc4zfQLwoNsaXSyh6i1aUBRQNKEpnW77L9UMOJLzhtMirH1WhhxaIetdgn_OnmDBw_CDGCt1nZ4CnZFsh-UPmgGHLyk2S-Hhv6wAg; here_auth=XzR4wWWedkxaVG67Y%2FDe0GtuMm5QWnpzTWM0dHIgB90DjehXuMUtxJQkq0dW6fWFNmm5X2uQC3E0%2FZ0U7eHlG3z1UKAutXU1Z9cQ5HvA%2BK40Bp3bqxHn40o3I0513PAVOVTFChgsyZ%2BuhNu4qTzDMonCJAykjQCb8Lry%2BK8R1zpg6tyYNWZsP9n%2BBRteM7tVvUll9D0XVFF0t9rSvYkMCIUjClgROupBLN7ok9Hb81gSBH0Z1R7wnNRkSkrZJb3kSwmIBo7fyHPbf2%2BF7dGCTv1xoTNpTBkCVkV41Bd8mSSt47%2BHhbJ%2FnEpeVjdBAaQ5pK%2FPr9W5sVBLhA%3D%3D; s_cc=true; s_sq=%5B%5BB%5D%5D; utag_main=v_id:01703c96a2130016de75df0ea7d70307900490710093c$_sn:14$_ss:0$_st:1588173371414$vapi_domain:here.com$ses_id:1588169854112%3Bexp-session$_pn:9%3Bexp-session; _totalpageviews=9; _biz_nA=77; _biz_pendingA=%5B%5D' \
  --compressed"
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a good question and I expect HERE maps support can answer this properly and hope eventually we will have information in the docs. I also have similar behavior when having too many waypoints. The only info I found in terms of docs is [here](https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/3.15/api_reference_java/index.html?com%2Fhere%2Fandroid%2Fmpa%2Frouting%2FRoutePlan.html) and it's android SDK docs.

A quote from the mentioned source:

> While there is no maximum limit imposed on how many waypoints are allowed for a route, increasing the number of waypoints increases the probability that the route request will fail and a safe upper limit of 128 is recommended.

I believe a similar approach works for REST API as well. But let's wait HERE Developer Support answer